Snakemake rules that are dependent on checkpoint outputs skipped
I currenltly have a Snakefile with the following checkpoint & rules:
checkpoint a:
    input: "some_bam.bam"
    output:
        info="some_info.info"
        zip="some_zip.gz"

rule sub:
    input:
        info = lambda wc: checkpoint.a.get(**wc).output.info,
        file = "some_file.txt"
    output:
        "sub_out.out"

checkpoint b:
    input:
        zip = lambda wc: checkpoints.a.get(**wc).output.zip
        some_other_file = "some_other_file.txt"
    output:
        "cbout.out"

(shell/scripts seemed irrelevant to this problem so I skipped those)
When I run the snakefile, for some reaason the sub rule is not run and goes straight from checkpoint a to checkpoint b. Dry-running the pipeline with the command snakemake --forceall -n --until sub built DAG of 0 jobs. Seems like Snakemake is ignoring the rule altogether and I'm not sure why.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! I'm currently using Snakemake version 8.25.3.
